# Issue with docsethomepage.aspx webpart on SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, web-part

We had a SharePoint 2010 environment. Under that we have page called as "docsethomepage.aspx". On document set home page, we had some webparts like "Document Set Properties", "Document Set Contents", "Note Board" and "Workflow History".

We are facing some issue with Note Board web part. Suppose on document set home page, under "Document set contents" web part, we added 40 to 50 documents and given some "comments" on "Note Board" on the page.

Now, On "Document set home page", document are showing up to 30 because we set "Number of items to display limit as 30" and comments are also showing and its' fine. But when we click for next for seeing remaining other documents on page, it's showing the remaining other documents but "comments" are not showing. Only main page "comments" are showing on "Note Board".

My requirement was "comments" need to come along when we click on next button also. Hope understand my issue. Please help on this issue.